# OpenSSH accesslog : Logging ciphers, MAC and user agent

Tags: logs, openssh, algorithms

How to log the `Protocol`, `KexAlgorithm`, `Cipher` and `MAC` algorithm negociated by the client and the client's user agent string?

What I'm looking for is the OpenSSH equivalent to Apache HTTPD's [CustomLog+LogFormat+mod_ssl](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_ssl.html#logformats) `%{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x` + `%{User-agent}i`

I want to log (on the server side) the same information that are availiable on the client side :

```
$ ssh -v localhost 2>&1 |grep kex
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
```

+

```
$ ssh -v localhost 2>&1 |grep version
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7
```

Comment: Increase log level to `sshd`?  See `man 5 sshd_config | less +/LogLevel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use at least `LogLevel DEBUG` to see these message in the server log. Also do not forget to restart the `sshd` service after the change.

```
sshd[31049]: debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u3

sshd[31049]: debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none [preauth]
sshd[31049]: debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none [preauth]
```

If you mean SSH client version by the "user agent".

Also note that there will be a lot of more information in the logs. If you use RHEL/Fedora, these information should be already in the `audit` log (except the client software version).

Comment: It was indeed a silly question of mine : I wen't up to VERBOSE but I never thought this would also be at DEBUG level on the server side ;) Thanks

Comment: Manual page for `sshd_config` is your friend :)